# Complex analysis: given the radius of convergence of one series, how can I find radii of convergence for other series?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose I know that:

$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} c_k z^k$ is $R$.  How can I use this to find the radius of convergence for something like:

$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} 3^k c_k z^k$

$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} k^2 c_k z^k$

$\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} c_k z^{k+5}$

Comment: How do you find the radius of convergence? Once you know for the first series, notice that rest of the series are not very much different, try to find the radius of convergence of the second one and see that something similar with the first would come up where you need to use $R$. Try it.

Comment: the idea is the same for computing the ROC of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k R^{-k}$